# Find Traffic lights on Mapquest api

Tags: android, maps, mapquest

I am using Mapquest Api to draw a route on android which is perfect for now. I am also trying to find out features or points from the JsonResponse object to see if I can classify certain points as Intersections or Traffic lights.
Does anybody know how to find traffic lights or Intersections on mapquest?

Answer (score 0):

This data is not exposed in the route or guidance apis. I will forward this on to the teams as an enhancement request.

Comment: Wow Thanks! This feature; If it is released will surly help us a lot. My guidance module depends a lot on this data and its accuracy. Hope to see it released soon.

Comment: An Update: One work around for this is to inspect the maneuverType values under GuidanceNodeCollection from the JSONObject that is obtained from the API call. Values between 1 and 7 indicate that a turn or an intersection is expected at that lat and lng values.